# C++ NDK library memory management for jobjectarray return method

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-ndk, java-native-interface

// ***** New question. *****

There is a memory leak below when the struct is being passed to a thread. Can not understand why, as the code inside the thread if called directly in the main thread does not leak memory.

```
class PeopleCounting{

  // Class variables
  Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> pMOG2 = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(500, 16);
  Mat maskBackgroundSubtracted = Mat(resizeDimension.height, resizeDimension.width, CV_8UC1);

  // Thread creation code below, code called from main.

    //Create thread
    pthread_t threads;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void *status;

    // Initialize and set thread joinable
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    // Creating thread data and initializing it
    BackgroundSubstractionThreadData threadData = {CamImage, maskBackgroundSubtracted, pMOG2};
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&threads, NULL, performBackgroundSubstraction, (void *)&threadData);
    if (rc)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APPNAME, "Error: peopleCountingMainMono unable to create thread  - %d",rc);
    }
    // free attribute and wait for the other threads
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    // ************** Do something else in main thread **************

    // Join thread i.e. wait till completion of thread
    rc = pthread_join(threads, &status);
    if (rc)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APPNAME, "Error: peopleCountingMainMono unable to join - %d",rc);
    }

    // Using class variable **maskBackgroundSubtracted** and **pMOG2** for later use. **CamImage** (opencv mat) usually gets released automatically in general due to smart pointer implementation, not sure if it is the source of leak

}

// Note: Outside class
void *performBackgroundSubstraction(void *threadarg)
  {
  struct BackgroundSubstractionThreadData *my_data;
  my_data = (struct BackgroundSubstractionThreadData *)threadarg;

  Mat fgMask;
  my_data->pMOG2F->apply(my_data->leftCamImage, fgMask, 0.002);

  morphologyEx(fgMask, fgMask, MORPH_OPEN, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3)),Point(-1,-1),1);
  morphologyEx(fgMask, fgMask, MORPH_CLOSE, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(11, 11)),Point(-1,-1),1);
  threshold(fgMask, my_data->dst, 128, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  };
```

// ***** End of question ****

I have a NDK library having a JNI function which returns **jobjectArray**

In below code, I am using a static global jPeopleCountArray which is filled with jobject via a loop and returned to Java calling method. This JNI function is called again and again via a loop from my Java code but only one instance at a time, thus allowing for a global return object. I perform memory cleanup at the end of library use by looping through the jobject array and deleting local ref of jobjects and finally deleting global ref of jPeopleCountArray. The memory cleanup is performed only at the very end as the iterative use (but only single instance) allows reuse of return object.

The question is when I am assigning the global **jobjectArray** through **NewObjectArray**. Does the all jobjects previously held inside the jobjectArray due to the previous call gets freed from memory?

```
class PeopleCounting{
  public:
    static inline jobjectArray jPeopleCountArray = NULL;
    static inline JNI_PEOPLECOUNT * jniPeopleCount = NULL;
  // .... Rest of Code ...
}


// JNI function
    PeopleCounting *obj = (PeopleCounting *) hEngineHandle;

    obj->LoadJniPeopleCount(env);
    Mat *pMatCGray = (Mat *) addrCamGray;

    vector<PeopleSegment> peopleCountingFromContourRes = obj->peopleCountingMainMono(
            *pMatCGray);

    // ******** IMPORTANT BELOW *********        
    obj->jPeopleCountArray = env->NewObjectArray(peopleCountingFromContourRes.size(),
                                            obj->jniPeopleCount->cls, NULL);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < peopleCountingFromContourRes.size(); i++) {
        jobject jPeopleCount = env->NewObject(obj->jniPeopleCount->cls,
                                              obj->jniPeopleCount->constructortorID);
        obj->FillPeopleCountValuesToJni(env, jPeopleCount, peopleCountingFromContourRes[i]);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(obj->jPeopleCountArray, i, jPeopleCount);
    }
    return obj->jPeopleCountArray;



// Memory cleanup at the end of library use.
PeopleCounting *obj = (PeopleCounting *) hEngineHandle;
if (obj->jPeopleCountArray != NULL){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME,
                        "Freeing memory of jobject array");
    //https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/index.html
    int size = env->GetArrayLength(obj->jPeopleCountArray);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        jobject row = env->GetObjectArrayElement(obj->jPeopleCountArray, i);
        if(env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
            break;
        }
        env->DeleteLocalRef(row);
    }
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(obj->jPeopleCountArray);
}

delete (PeopleCounting *)(hEngineHandle);
```

Comment: I don't understand where a memory leak happens and what leads you to believe it happens. In general, I prefer to avoid pthread_exit. Return 0 from the thread function is usually enough to quit the thread gracefully.

Comment: @AlexCohn: You absolutely nailed it, pthread_exit was the culprit, changing it to return 0 solved the issue.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Although this solved the memory leak majorly. But I can see that after every 10K iteration the Native memory footprint as reported by android studio profiler is increasing by 10-15 MB. The library is supposed to be used in a 24x7 environment, so can not afford such issue. This ever increasing memory footprint issue is not present when the code is executed from main thread. Seems like multithreading is costing stability.

Comment: Please try to open a separate question to avoid clutter. Also, provide more info about what you are trying to achieve (why you need a joinable thread), what you mean by 20K iterations (is is 20000 times pthread_create(), or the loop happens in thread function), etc. Maybe you can manage your worker thread from Java?

Comment: I call this native method again and again from my java code in loop. The class instance is preserved for all the calls, so the class variable hold their data. The thread is detached to do some parallel processing, while I go ahead with some heavier task on main thread. Once the heavier task on main thread has finished, the need for joinable thread is to make sure that the thread has returned, if not I wait till completion of the thread and then go ahead in the main thread and combine the results from both thread as well as previous main thread heavier task.

Comment: Also, I retesting the library. Maybe the earlier reported bloating memory footprint as reported by Android Studio was wrong, as now it has settled around 70-80 MB after I restarted Android Studio.

Comment: Please remember that you should never do heavy processing on main thread in Android. As for spawning secondary threads often, it's not a good practice IMHO. Consider some Executor with thread loop to handle repeated requests.

Comment: Ofcourse it is not traditional main thread of android (UI). It is secondary thread spawned using handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could exhaust the very limited local references table (its size is implementation-dependent, but could be as low as 256).

You may delete the local reference to **jPeopleCount** inside the loop where it's created, right after `SetObjectArrayElement(…, jPeopleCount)`. On the other hand, all these local references will be released automatically after the JNI function returns **obj->jPeopleCountArray**.

Similarly, the loop that deletes local references to elements of **obj->jPeopleCountArray** is redundant. There exist no local references to deal with before you create these with **GetObjectArrayElement()**.

This demonstrates the difference of behavior between local references and global references. You don't need to create global references to each element of a **jobjectArray**. But if you were storing the **jPeopleCount** objects in a C++ collection (e.g. array), you would need *global references* for each. In this case, the cleanup code would loop over the collection and release these global references, similar to your code.

Comment: Can you take a look at the new question added here? It is causing memory leak for me. I can not add a new question from my account due to stackoverflow limitation. Thanks again.

Comment: It's the first time I hear about SO limiting the ability to ask questions. Could it have been some temporary bug?